# NestJs merging 2 DTOs or best practices

Tags: node.js, nestjs, dto, nestjs-swagger

I have one common Dto for Pagination. But while some of the apis need more parameters and pagination too. e.g. search, filter etc. So my method would become like below :

```
 getAllCelebrities(
        @AuthUser('_id') userId: string,
        @Body() paginationnewDto: PaginationnewDto,
        @Body() getCelebritiesDto: GetCelebritiesDto,
    )
```

Having 2 body params generates 2 blocks in swagger. Like below:
[image]

Also when I console both params, it returns same object.

#### What is the best practice for this such that I don't have to put pagination params in my `getCelebritiesDto`? And I can be DRY.

Comment: I guess you can use simple inheritance, why not?

Comment: @MorKadosh I have this in mind as last option, I'm just looking if there's any other best practice.

Comment: Yes. I know that feeling when you think that a solution is too obvious. On the other hand, we are talking about plain classes, nothing more. So it might be that the obvious solution is the best one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own Question as I didn't find any other alternative. As per my thought and @MorKadosh's suggestion here is a simple solution. I've extended `PaginationnewDto` in `GetCelebritiesDto`

```
export class GetCelebritiesDto extends PaginationnewDto {}
```

Comment: Same thing happened with me. I was looking for a standard way to do this Nest. Found IntersectionType, but for that, have to create an extra class, so now using simple inheritance :)